# Javascript, undefined Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, undefined

Im trying to split the elements of an array, filled with strings and make if the separate elements a new one. When I debug, I become as warning, that the arr[l] is undefined, but I can't see why. Can somebody tell me?

```
...
var arrB=new Array();
for(var l=0; l<=arr.length; l++) {
console.log(arr[l].split(''));
arrB.push(arr[l].split('')); //Here
}
```

PS: in arr there are elements, it`s not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
for(var l=0; l<arr.length; l++)
```

(change <= to just <)

Comment: Dont I lose so my last element?

Comment: No, if the array length is 10, the last element will be at arr[9], because you start at 0, not 1.